# Understanding regression coefficient compared to another metric in the data (cost of acquisition)

Tags: r, regression

Hey All I have a stats question -

I'm looking at marketing data now. We have different marketing channels like:
Paid Search, Paid Social, OTT

We see how much we spend on any given day for each channel. We also see how many users we bring into the company from that marketing channel.

We create a new variable called CAC for cost of customer acquisition which is spend / users. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

My question is:

If I create a linear model that predicts Total_Orders based on Source_Group

```
lm_march <- lm(Total_Orders ~ Source_Group, all_march)
```

Is it definitely the case that the independent variables with the highest coefficients will be the ones with the lowest CAC?